# Send images in embeds discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send embeds in discord.py, but whenever i run the code nothing gets sent. No errors nothing. Here is my code:

```
from variables.variables import client, token
import discord


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    imageURL = "https://discordapp.com/assets/e4923594e694a21542a489471ecffa50.svg"
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=imageURL)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

This is what the embed looks like using above code:

[image: What the embed looks like]
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `on_command_error` event?If you have, print the error in there and post the error.

Comment: No there is no error, i just don't get any image, ill edit the post to show how the embed looks like

Comment: Are you sure that **.svg** type is supported?

Comment: no, but this is an image link i used from another stackoverflow question asking how to send images in embeds, as i dont know how to make an image http or https

Comment: Can you try some random **.png** image for url? So you can figure it out if the problem is the file type.

Comment: sorry for the wait my computer restarted randomly, i get an error when i do that:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.`

Answer (score 0):

`.svg` is not supported. Here's the same image in `.png` format:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    imageURL = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/744631318578462740/755866713182044240/ezgif-4-6eba1fde99f2.png"
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=imageURL)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked, but how did you convert the `.svg` file to `.png`

Comment: There's a bunch of websites online that can do it, just google "svg to png".